# How can I define validation rules for JAXB if not using XSD's?

Tags: validation, jaxb

So, we have a project that uses jaxb to marshal and unmarshal.  We on't have XSD's. We only have annotated Java objects.  So, when the xml comes into our system, we unmarshal it.  The JAXB docs talk about validating the java objects during the unmarshalling phase.  I would like to be able to add some validation rules somewhere ( annotations on the java source, next to the jaxb annotations, perhpas? ) that would give me a readable, maintainable, declarative style validation mechanism.  But I'm not sure that JAXB supports this; perhaps the JAXB validation is only driven by XSD's.  Suggestions?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBWorks2.html#wp82802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JAXB Validation (JSR-222)**

JAXB validation is based on an XML schema (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).

**Bean Validation (JSR-303 & 349)**

You could use Bean Validation [1.0 (JSR-303)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) or [1.1 (JSR-349)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349) annotations on your model to define validation rules.

Comment: Yes.  I can see that normally one would want to use XSD-driven data wrangling here . . . I'm not sure what the perceived benefits of not having schemas are, but that decision was made at a higher level.

Comment: @chad - That is where the Bean Validation JSRs come into play.  It is a standard for specifying standalone validation rules.

Comment: And it looks like Spring implements it so this should work well.  Thanks!